# Unbinding emacs keys for multi-term in emacs 23

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to setup multi-term for emacs 23, but the

```
(setq term-unbind-key-list '("C-z" "C-x" "C-c" "C-h" "C-y"))
```

line all the websites I've seen recommend for getting rid of key binding clashes doesn't work- I still can't C-z out of man pages for example. 
Did something change in emacs 23? How do I unbind them properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `term-unbind-key-list` only affects bindings in the key map `term-raw-map`.  You can find this out by looking at the documentation for the function `multi-term-keystroke-setup` (no idea why this information isn't available for the variable itself...)

> Keystroke setup of `term-char-mode'.
>
> By default, the key bindings of `term-char-mode' conflict with user's
>   keystroke. So this function unbinds some keys with`term-raw-map', and
>   binds some keystroke with `term-raw-map'.

So... likely the <kbd>C-z</kbd> is still bound to `suspend-frame` b/c that's what Emacs does by default.

If you want <kbd>C-z</kbd> to be bound to what it is normally in a terminal (`suspend-job`), you can do this:

```
(require 'multi-term)
(add-to-list 'term-bind-key-alist '("C-z" . term-stop-subjob))
```

Which makes the binding do what (I'm guessing) you want.

Comment: Thanks Trey. This is very helpful. Do you know if the lists `term-unbind-key-list` and `term-bind-keyalist` define the behavior for `character mode`, `line mode` or both? The reason why I ask is because I like the ability to switch between two different sets of keyboard shortcuts while I am on a terminal in Emacs. For example, in one mode, `C-n` would move to the previous line in the buffer as in regular Emacs, while in the other `C-n` would be sent to the terminal). Is this possible with multi-term using these lists?